# Custom post type archive sorted and grouped by date in post meta field

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, actions, archives, custom-post-type-archives

I am trying to build an Custom Post Type for showing information about events. The Custom Post Type has name 'Event', with the following meta fields:

- event_startdate *(date in format YYYY-MM-DD)*
- event_enddate *(date in format YYYY-MM-DD)*

This works fine for the single-event listing, however in the archive listing I would like to see a grouping like:

### 2019

#### March

- Title of event starting in march
- Title of another event starting in march

#### May

- Title of may event

#### December

- Title of Christmas event

### 2020

#### January

- Title of 2020 vision event

I have found some questions and answers on using wp_get_archives(), however this seems to group the posts by published date, rather on the actual date of the event (event.startdate). I also found some posts on sorting by metavalue, however not grouping. Thanks in advance for any advice or hint on how to accomplish this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so this problem has two parts:

1. Make WordPress to sort these posts properly.
2. Make WordPress to display them with all that grouping.

### 1. Sorting CPT by meta value on archive

You can use `pre_get_posts` to achieve this.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'event' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'meta_key', 'event_startdate' );
    }
} );
```

So now events will be sorted ascending by start_date.

### 2. Displaying and grouping

You'll have to modify the `archive-event.php` file, so these events get in their groups.

```
<?php
    $current_year = $current_month = '';

    while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();

        $last_year = $current_year;
        $last_month = $current_month;

        $current_year = date( 'Y', strtotime( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'event_startdate', true ) ) );
        if ( $last_year != $current_year ) {
            $last_month = '';
        }
        $current_month = date( 'F', strtotime( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'event_startdate', true ) ) );
?>
    <?php if ( $last_year != $current_year ) : ?><h2><?php echo $current_year; ?></h2><?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ( $last_month != $current_month ) : ?><h3><?php echo $current_month; ?></h3><?php endif; ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this wellwritten and excellent answer, which helped me a lot!

Comment: @OleKristianLosvik I guess you'd like to add some `ul`s in there, but it shouldn't be to hard, so I've omitted that part.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code from @krzysiek-dróżdż my `archive-eventi.php` is now like below. Posting it here incase anyone else is trying to achieve the same thing. Note that the event custom post type is named `eventi`.

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying event archive
 *
 * @package Eventi
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
get_header();
?>

    <section id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) :
            ?>

            <header class="page-header">
                <?php
                    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
                ?>
            </header><!-- .page-header -->

            <?php
            // Start the Loop.
            $args = [
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'post_type'      => 'eventi',
                'posts_per_page' => 100,
                'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
                'order'          => 'ASC',
                'meta_type'      => 'DATE',
                'meta_key'       => 'eventi_startdate',
            ];

            $posts         = new WP_Query( $args );
            $current_year  = '';
            $current_month = '';
            while ( $posts->have_posts() ) {
            ?>
            <article id="event-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                <div class="entry-content">
                <?php
                $posts->the_post();
                $post_id = get_the_id();

                $startdate  = strtotime( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'eventi_startdate', true ) );
                $enddate    = strtotime( get_post_meta( $post_id, 'eventi_enddate', true ) );
                $dateformat = get_option( 'date_format' );

                $last_year    = $current_year;
                $last_month   = $current_month;
                $current_year = date_i18n( 'Y', $startdate );
                if ( $last_year != $current_year ) {
                    $last_month = '';
                }
                $current_month = date_i18n( 'F', $startdate );

                if ( $last_year != $current_year ) {
                    echo '<h2>' . $current_year . '</h2>';
                }

                if ( $last_month != $current_month ) {
                    echo '<h3>' . $current_month . '</h3>';
                }

                $post_id = get_the_ID();
                if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) {
                    printf( '<span class="sticky-post">%s</span>', _x( 'Featured', 'post', 'eventi' ) );
                }
                echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" class="event-details-link">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
                echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . get_the_excerpt();

                // Date and times


                echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;&mdash;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . date_i18n( $dateformat, $startdate );
                if ( $startdate !== $enddate ) {
                    echo ' - ' . date_i18n( $dateformat, $enddate );
                }

                ?>
                </div>
            </article>
            <?php
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();

            // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        else :
            ?>
            <section class="no-results not-found">
                <header class="page-header">
                    <h1 class="page-title"><?php _e( 'No events yet!', 'eventi' ); ?></h1>
                </header><!-- .page-header -->

                <div class="page-content">
                    <?php
                    if ( current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) ) :

                        printf(
                            '<p>' . wp_kses(
                                /* translators: 1: link to WP admin new post page. */
                                __( 'Ready to publish your first event? <a href="%1$s">Get started here</a>.', 'eventi' ),
                                array(
                                    'a' => array(
                                        'href' => array(),
                                    ),
                                )
                            ) . '</p>',
                            esc_url( admin_url( 'post-new.php?post_type=eventi' ) )
                        );
                    else :
                        ?>

                        <p><?php _e( 'It seems we can&rsquo;t find any events.', 'eventi' ); ?></p>
                        <?php

                    endif;
                    ?>
                </div><!-- .page-content -->
            </section><!-- .no-results -->
            <?php
        endif;
        ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php
get_footer();
```